# How to properly serialize/deserialize a map in dart/flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Can you please show how to serialize/desierialize a map<> to/from json in dart? For example, here's a simple data Class:

```
class SimpleData {
  int _blah;
  String _str;

  SimpleData([this._blah, this._str]);

  SimpleData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _blah = json['b'];
    _str = json['s'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'b' : _blah,
    's' : _str,
  };
}
```

Here's the SimpleData class used in a map:

```
class MapTest {
  Map<int, SimpleData> _mapHell = Map<int, SimpleData>();

  MapTest() {
    _mapHell[1] = SimpleData(42, "Astfgl");
    _mapHell[666] = SimpleData(1234, "Vassenego");
  }

  MapTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _mapHell = jsonDecode(json['coworkers']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'coworkers' : jsonEncode(_mapHell),
  };
}
```

Now, when calling `MapTest.toJson()`, the following error is thrown:

> Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:2

Do you have any ideas whats wrong with the `toJson()/fromJson()` methods? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encoding/decoding is correct, only that JSON only allows strings as the key.
Change `_mapHell` to `Map<String, SimpleData>` will work fine.

```dart
class MapTest {
  final _mapHell = Map<String, SimpleData>(); // Change the Map type

  MapTest() {
    _mapHell['1'] = SimpleData(42, "Astfgl"); // Use int, ie: '1'
    _mapHell['666'] = SimpleData(1234, "Vassenego");
  }

  MapTest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _mapHell = jsonDecode(json['coworkers']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'coworkers' : jsonEncode(_mapHell),
  };
}
```